# What does this Notation mean: N."some cumulative distribution function"?

Tags: notation, probability-distributions

What does $N.\hat{N}_{fa}(S)$ mean, when $\hat{N}_{fa}(S)$ is a cumulative distribution function? $\hat{N}_{fa}(S) = \sum\limits_{s=0}^{S}\hat{p}_{fa}(s)$

The formula is from this paper (section 4.2): [Logo Retrieval with A Contrario Visual Query Expansion](http://kusu.comp.nus.edu.sg/proceedings/mm09/mm/p581.pdf)

Comment: A bit of context would be nice. (Where did you see this written?)

Comment: Sure, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure $N$ in the context means the size of the set $\Omega$, the total number of images. See beginning of section 3.1 of the linked paper. And in $N.\hat{N}_{fa}(S)$, the $.$ should just be multiplication. So the entire term should be interpreted as a distribution of the number of false alarms (total number times the cumulative distribution).

Comment: Thank you, that sounds reasonable. I guess I was thinking too complicated. Given that it is just a normal multiplication, am I right if I consider this as bad formatting?

Comment: @tauran: good and bad formatting is partly subjective (although there are of course guides like the _Chicago Manual of Style_); that said, I feel that you are quite justified in feeling that way.